# The whole POI sheet is getting locked

Tags: java, eclipse, struts, apache-poi

I am protecting a HSSFSheet with password. But the whole sheet is getting locked while doing this where I want to lock the first three rows.

Comment: How are you doing the locking? (Code would help)

Comment: HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");
  
  worksheet.protectSheet("password");